# Repository mapping to fixed path

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

As part of my build, I want to map a sub folder to a fixed folder on the c:\ drive.

The problem is when I try and map it, I get this :

[image]

How can I change the local path on 1 item to not be prefixed with $(build.sourceDirectory)?

Comment: So you want to copy all the source files into C:\drive during get source file step?

Comment: @Eddie, no I ideally want them mapped there directly. So during "get source" it gets the sources there in 1 operation, without having to a) get from TFS then b) copy.

Comment: Is this applicable for all the build definitions? If yes, you can change the work folder of your build agent to C:\ drive.

Answer (score 0):

A file path input (has ...) defaults to relative paths.（In **Mappings**, it is **Server Path**） A relative path is relative to the root of the repo in build and root of artifact downloaded in RM. **Build sources directory** happens to point to the root of the repo.

So the **Local Path** is  prefixed with `$(build.sourceDirectory)`. It's by designed. You **can't** change the local path on 1 item to not be prefixed with it.

In your situation, the fixed path  clearly should be out of the path on the build agent where your source code files are downloaded. So suggest you to use the **copy files Task** to achieve what you need. **However, you may have to set the fixed path as an *UNC shared path*.**

[image]

---

Update

After go through [the extension info](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/overview), seems the copy task is the only solution for now.  And you could add a powershell script, after the first copy ,  compare the  sub folder in TFS server with the fixed path.  Then you just need to copy the new add things in the sub folder to the fixed path.

Comment: Hi, As much as I like your suggestion, the problem is that this folder contains GB's of data. And would chronically slow down my build process.

Comment: You can use a **Archive Files** task (https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/steps/utility/archive-files) to  archive the  source folder first . If you need to Extract Files during the build, you can **Extract Files** task( https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/steps/utility/extract-files)

Comment: No, I mean I don't want it compressed, other projects reference DLL's in these "external" folders. Ideally I just want to be able to map the repositories to fixed drives, it would solve the issue.

Comment: After go through the extension info (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/overview ), little help, seems the copy task is the only solution for now.  Or you could add a powershell script, after the first copy ,  compare the  sub folder in TFS server with the fixed path.  Then you just need to copy the new add things in the sub folder to the fixed path.